# Kotlin - how to make an onClick function referrable through a fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm trying to implement a simple rating bar (`rb`) in Android Studio using Kotlin. To test out the rating bar (X stars out of 5), I'm using the Toast function to display the designated rating value upon clicking the "Apply" button (`button`). I'm currently working in a fragment, which I believe is the source of my issue. All of this code is within the fragment's `override fun onCreateView(...)): View? {` section.

```
    btn = root.findViewById<View>(R.id.button) as Button
    rb = root.findViewById<View>(R.id.rb) as RatingBar

    fun click(view: View) {
        val ratingvalue = rb.rating
        Toast.makeText(context!!, "Rating is: " + ratingvalue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

The function name `click` is grayed-out, stating that it is never called. To clarify, I have designated this to be the button's onClick function name, as so: `android:onClick="click"`. When clicking the button, no text shows up and the app crashes.

Any insight to this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your error log?

Comment: "Could not find method click(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution.

1.Remove `android:onClick="click"` from Button in your fragment layout file, like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

2.In your fragment class, remove `click()` method and add this

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)

    btn = root.findViewById<View>(R.id.button) as Button
    rb = root.findViewById<View>(R.id.rb) as RatingBar
    btn.setOnClickListener {
        val ratingvalue = rb.rating
        Toast.makeText(context!!, "Rating is: " + ratingvalue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    return root
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set click event to your button programmatically:

```
btn = root.findViewById<View>(R.id.button) as Button
btn.setOnClickListener {
    val ratingvalue = rb.rating
    Toast.makeText(context!!, "Rating is: " + ratingvalue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue as before

Comment: Can you try to set click event in Activity instead of your xml? Check my code above

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `tools:context="<file path to your fragment>"` defined in the root layout of your Fragment xml, for example: `tools:context=".ui.registration.RegistrationFragment"`.

**tools:context** is used to find the correct place to insert your *onClick* handler.

Answer (score 0):

Just write as this way. It worked for me.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculate, container, false)
    val buttonCalculate = root.findViewById(R.id.buttonCalculate) as Button

    buttonCalculate.setOnClickListener() {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Hola ratita", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    return root
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves on the existing answers the question has, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.